# Where are a JavaScript's class' instance methods stored?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Given:

```
var car = class Car{
    drive() {}
    park(){}
}
```

Given car, how can I find what methods this class has,
ie "drive" and "park" ?
I would have thought they were on

car.prototype

It's true that

```
car.prototype.drive
```

returns the method
and

```
car.prototype.hasOwnProperty("drive") => true
```

but

```
for(let prop_name in car.prototype){
    console.log(prop_name)
}
```

prints nothing.

Comment: `for in` is weird.

Comment: Not certain what question is?

Comment: You answered your own question: they are stored on the prototype object. For why `for in` doesn't enumerate them, and how to access them instead, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The property is not enumerable (`car.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("drive") === false`), therefore it doesn't show it. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in original insertion order

Otherwise you are correct, the function is on the prototype.

Note that this is **not** and instance method. An instance method exists once per instance, as the name already implies. You can generate instance methods e.g. with

```
class car {
  constructor() {
    this.instanceFunc = () => {};
  }
}
```

Note here that explicitly `new car().instanceFunc !== new car().instanceFunc`

Comment: ‘An instance method exists once per instance’ Not exactly. In JavaScript, *instance methods* means accessible from an instance, and *static methods* means accessible from a class. Instance methods can be shared by all instances (if you declare them on the instances’ prototype, that is as *methods* in a `class` body) or specific to each instance (if you declare them on the instances, that is as *fields* in a `class` body or as properties of `this` in methods of a `class` body). Check out the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_Classes).

Comment: For instance, with `class A {x; static y; f() {} static g() {} constructor() {this.z = 0}}`, you get: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A)`
returns `['length', 'name', 'prototype', 'g', 'y']`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A.prototype)` returns `['constructor', 'f']`, and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new A)` returns `['x', 'z']`.